# Invoice Customization doesn't seem to work

Tags: invoice

I'm trying to change the logo that appears on our invoice PDFs. Based on this [this section of the docs](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/invoicing/#invoice-customization), I am in `Administer > Communications > Message Templates`. I had tried customizing the invoice before and it no longer appears under `System Workflow Messages` as mentioned in the docs but instead in the personalized messages section.

Changing the HTML format field doesn't do anything. I tried adding text to test out the changes but it doesn't work. I'm not quite sure what else I can do. I am using WordPress. Any help?

Comment: I can confirm that I have been able to customize invoice PDFs and that as far as I know it's still possible. I can also see how my message templates are duplicated as you also observed.